# What is the correct sentence? Please, help!

Tags: word-usage

may I say: temperature was higher than average from May to October?

Comment: Why do you think you couldn't say that?

Comment: If you prepend a The, then yes you may

Comment: Where _should_ people go to ask questions like this?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature was higher than average for the months May through to October.

Comment: you need *of* after *months*.

Comment: Either actually I'd say. The omission of of is a common shorthand

Comment: ... It's not very common in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm in the UK. This language is usually used in a semi-technical context and you would normally omit "of" in these situations. The sentence wouldn't be used much outside the likes of a geography book etc imo, you'd use a less formal expression. In fairness "to" should go as well given what I've just said, so "months May through October". Definitely think "of" 'disturbs' the relationship to the later part of the sentence in this situation however.

Comment: You may be here in the UK, but I bet I can guess where the geography books were written.

Comment: Micronesia, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence sounds okay. The only thing as @mplungjan mentioned is you need *the* at the beginning, unless that part is missing from the quoted text only.

> The temperature was higher than average...